# Google Play button not visible on Flutter App

Tags: android, flutter, google-pay

Package I am using - [pay: ^1.0.8](https://pub.dev/packages/pay)

This error seems to be coming when I am running adb log-cat in a terminal connected to a real device and the Google Pay button is not visible instead childOnError is triggered.

Below is the Error -

```
04-01 02:23:13.308 3020 15516 W TapAndPay: shouldEnableGooglePay: false [CONTEXT service_id=79 ]
04-01 02:23:13.308 3020 15516 I TapAndPay: Disabling TapAndPay HCE service [CONTEXT service_id=79 ]
04-01 02:23:13.375 3020 15516 W TapAndPay: shouldEnableGooglePay: false [CONTEXT service_id=79 ]
04-01 02:23:13.376 3020 15516 I TapAndPay: Disabling TapAndPay HCE service [CONTEXT service_id=79 ]
04-01 02:23:13.400 3020 15516 W TapAndPay: shouldEnableGooglePay: false [CONTEXT service_id=79 ]
04-01 02:23:13.400 3020 15516 I TapAndPay: Disabling TapAndPay HCE service [CONTEXT service_id=79 ]
04-01 02:23:13.409 3020 15516 W TapAndPay: shouldEnableGooglePay: false [CONTEXT service_id=79 ]
04-01 02:23:13.409 3020 15516 I TapAndPay: Disabling TapAndPay HCE service [CONTEXT service_id=79 ]
04-01 02:23:39.243 3020 15516 W TapAndPay: shouldEnableGooglePay: false [CONTEXT service_id=79 ]
04-01 02:23:39.243 3020 15516 I TapAndPay: Disabling TapAndPay HCE service [CONTEXT service_id=79 ]
04-01 02:23:39.267 3020 15516 W TapAndPay: shouldEnableGooglePay: false [CONTEXT service_id=79 ]
```

Below is the UI code-

```
                        GooglePayButton(
                        paymentConfigurationAsset: 'gpay.json',
                        paymentItems: [
                          PaymentItem(
                            label: 'Pay',
                            amount: newPlanCost,
                            status: PaymentItemStatus.final_price,
                          )
                        ],
                        width: 200,
                        height: 50,
                        style: GooglePayButtonStyle.black,
                        type: GooglePayButtonType.pay,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                        onPaymentResult: (paymentResult) {
                          print(paymentResult);
                          voucherCheckoutHandler(
                            paymentCheckout.newPlanName,
                            paymentCheckout.newPlanDealAmount,
                            uid,
                          );
                        },
                        childOnError: Text('Error'),
                        loadingIndicator: const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try in this way

```
GooglePayButton(
        paymentConfigurationAsset:
            'default_payment_profile_google_pay.json',
        paymentItems: _paymentItems,
        style: GooglePayButtonStyle.black,
        type: GooglePayButtonType.pay,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
        onPaymentResult: onGooglePayResult,
        loadingIndicator: const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
      ApplePayButton(
        paymentConfigurationAsset: 'default_payment_profile_apple_pay.json',
        paymentItems: _paymentItems,
        style: ApplePayButtonStyle.black,
        type: ApplePayButtonType.buy,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
        onPaymentResult: onApplePayResult,
        loadingIndicator: const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
```

for more checkout this git code : [pay-Main.dart](https://github.com/google-pay/flutter-plugin/blob/main/pay/example/lib/main.dart)

Comment: I am doing the same thing, as shown above, but the Google Pay button is not appearing instead childOnError is triggered. I have added the error which is appearing on adb log-cat

Comment: Checkout this github open source code : https://github.com/search?q=GooglePayButton+flutter&type=Code

Comment: One of the easiest I found for you : [Google Pay](https://github.com/icchigoo/Canteen-Resturant/blob/b05d72762e91a04491b411f67cb00fcd627a534e/lib/payment_summary/my_google_pay.dart)

Comment: I updated the ui code above instead of GooglePayButton appearing, Text('Error') is appearing.

Comment: i think you need to edit question with more info.

Comment: What other details do you need? I have added what is happening with me "This error seems to be coming when I am running adb log-cat in a terminal connected to a real device. The Google Pay button is not visible; instead, childOnError is triggered."